# Force rebuild after Spring config file edit

Tags: c#, visual-studio, build, spring.net

In our C# project we use Spring as an Inversion of Control (IoC) container. We noticed, that changes to the Spring configuration xml file do not cause the solution to be rebuild. Therefore the changed configuration is not copied to the output folder and every debug-run uses the old configuration.

How can we force Visual Studio (2008) to copy the config file even though none of the project code has changed?

Further info:
The build action of the config file is set to *None*. Copy to Output Directory is set to *Copy always*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the solution is simpler than I thought. If the build action for the *.xml config file is changed to `Embedded Resource`, then changing the file also touches the project. Therefore, every debug cycle causes a rebuild of the project, where the config file is included. This causes the file to be copied to the output directory with the adjusted configuration. => Problem solved.

Comment: but an embedded resource puts the file into the assembly you won't be able to configure anything after the publish...

Comment: That is true. Bute while debugging, I change the configuration only, in order to test several different scenarios. Once we have a release deployment, we will have to change the build action again.